# Can i use npm link to attach React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have two separate projects both scaffolded with create-react-app.
First on - UI contains simple ui library. It's just a bunch of simple components with project structure like this:

```
app
 src
   CustomButton.js
   ...
```

Nothing unusual. Just a bunch of simple react components. And the second one is application itself.

Is it possible to use npm link to add UI project as dependency? I want to be able to import components from UI project like this:

```
import {CustomButton} from 'UI';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do this quite often. From the [npm link docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link#description):

> Package linking is a two-step process.
>
> First, npm link in a package folder will create a symlink in the global folder {prefix}/lib/node_modules/ that links to the package where the npm link command was executed. It will also link any bins in the package to {prefix}/bin/{name}. Note that npm link uses the global prefix (see npm prefix -g for its value).
>
> Next, in some other location, npm link package-name will create a symbolic link from globally-installed package-name to node_modules/ of the current folder.
>
> Note that package-name is taken from package.json, not from directory name.

Example:

```
cd ~/projects/my-components-lib  # go into the package directory
npm link                         # creates global link
cd ~/projects/my-app             # go into some other package directory.
npm link my-components-lib       # link-install the package
```

Comment: SyntaxError: C:\temp\ui\src\components\button.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (4:12):

  2 | 
  3 | export const Button = (props) => {
> 4 |     return <button {...props}>{props.caption}</button>
    |            ^
  5 | }

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. fvx
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

Comment: Sounds like something wrong with the app configuration. I doubt this is a result of npm link. Are you able to render JSX in that app outside of an npm module?

Comment: there is absolutely nothing wrong with configuration because i used create-react-app without any modifications

Comment: I did a quick test and set up a new CRA. I linked a simple lib I created that exported a basic component and I got the same error you mentioned. I then tried it again but this time I installed a real package from npm (randomstring) and I cloned it, then linked that. There were no issues, and I was able to modify the cloned version and see changes in the app. This heavily suggests the issue is something to do with the config of the linked lib.

Comment: There must be more to this than just npm link?  Surely the first project ("my-components-lib") must be just a collection of source files (i.e. not an application itself, eg. using CRA), and possibly also exporting them (from its index.js) ?  @DeanJames any chance you could expose a bit more information about exactly what your "my-components-lib" looks like, and an example of using a component inside it from "my-app" ?  thanks!